# ASP.NET Caching Layer Vs Business Logic Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, n-tier-architecture

I'm looking for some helpful advice on how the caching layer in an ASP.NET project should work with the business logic layer. Specifically, should the caching layer handle **only** cached/cachable objects and pass other functions straight-through to the BLL or should the caching layer almost take the place of the BLL and leave that to just being the bridge between the caching layer and the DAL?

A good example of this and the one that has me scratching my head is basket functionality on an ecommerce website. Pre-caching layer, items were added to cart via the BLL to the DAL. At the BLL there's lots of logic for checking types of items etc. Should the caching layer now take responsibility for some of this logic or just pull the cached info together and pass it all through to the BLL?

I'd appreciate anyone's help on this.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you are caching. If I understood your question correctly, the caching in your scenario take the place of your data source; it doesn't replace your business logic or other layers.
In your shopping basket example, when you put the items in the basket, you cache those items so that you don't have to get them from their permanent storage often. However, if you have a logic that needs to check the items frequently, then you still do that, but by checking the items in the cached basket.

Comment: Thank you @TheBlueSky. Yes you understood my question correctly although I maybe didn't explain it as best I could.  In my example, I'm only really adding to data, I'm not really interacting with the cache (because I'm not caching baskets) but let's say I'm just returning a basic date from the BLL,  I would say this goes in the BLL and is accessed via the caching layer but this seems very long winded. Would this be best-practice with a caching layer in place?

Comment: Another perfect example here is where I'm interacting with an API in the BLL, it surely can't be 'the way' to add additional assembly references to the API in the caching layer, to then do the actual work in the BLL?

Comment: @JoeNinety, can you put together an example that demonstrate your case; maybe the date example you mentioned?